Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in Angular 7.3 and .net 8 Application
I recently migrated Angular/.net 8 Application from .net core 2.1 to .net 8. The application runs fine in my debug mode. However, when I deployed the application to IIS, it bombs with the 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' error.As I compared the updated application behaviour to the current one, I see that the angular built JS scripts runtime*, pollyfills*, main* and scripts* are HTML files rather than JS files. These same files in the dist folder look as JS files upon inspection. What is the cause of this? I checked the pathing of the files and the it's same angular file structure in both apps.
Any lights shed on this is greatly appreciated.

Used dotnet publish command
Used VS 2022 publish command also to generate the deployment package to no avail.
Copied over dist folder with the dist folder in my machine.

error

that's usually the backend returning an error in the form of an HTML page.  (probably a 404, check path/routing)  Right-click on the page, choose View Page Source.  You should be able to click on the src's to the scripts there.  See what appears.

Thanks for your comment. The old application though has the same pathing, same access rights, same database access rights and it works when I deploy it everytime.

you should check by clicking on the src's in page source, or just using static url to one of those scripts.  See what the backend is returning.  That'll give you a clue as to what's happening.

View source unfortunately doesn't shed any light on this issue.

you can probably click those links right in the error message you show, too.  That should tell you what the response is.

Issue resolved, seems to have been a compilation error due to not recognizing new code to compile. I'd advise folks to not set the compatibility to older version of .net Core and making sure new modified C# files are compiled.
